# How can I save a node group for later use without going through a blend file?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I saw Blender Guru giving downloads to these node groups that you could directly append into blender without having to go through a .blend file. How can I do that with my own node groups?

[image: my node group]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easy, you don't need extra .blend files and no python script for that:

1. Open up Blender, this way the default startup file is loaded.
2. Append the group you want to have at startup in the *Shader Editor*, give it a useful name if it doesn't already have one.
3. Check the *Fake User* (shield) symbol on the node group and delete it. The *Fake User* protects the group from being erased upon saving although being unused. If you don't delete it in the *Shader Editor*, it will stay in the default material of the default cube.

[image: protect group]

4. You could now save the startup file from the menu *File* > *Defaults* > *Save Startup File*. Note that changes you have made like the editor windows, the render engine etc. will be saved as default as well, so make sure you didn't change too much beforehand or bring it back into a state you want for the default.
5. If you now restart Blender or open a new file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *General*, you will find the node group in the *Shader Editor* under <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Add* > *Group*.

[image: add group]

Comment: thank you that helped

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own node groups (*Geometry Nodes*, *Shading Editor*, *Compositor*) and then save the file as regular .blend file. You can then use these files like libraries and append the node groups to any file. Say you created a new file or opened an existing file and you needed your custom node group, you can do the following:

## Method-1: Navigate NodeTree

`1` Go to *File > Append...*
`2` Browse to your .blend file containing your custom node group
`3` Double click the .blend file and navigate to *NodeTree*
`4` There you will see your custom nodes. Select it and click *Append*

In this example I'm importing a *Geometry Nodes* custom *Node Group* but you can do the same in any Node Editor.

[image]

You can press <kbd>F3</kbd> in the Node Editor and search for the name of your node group and select it.

## Method-2: Using Python

You can also import your node groups via python with the following script:

```
import bpy

path = "path/to/your/blend/file.blend"

with bpy.data.libraries.load(path) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.node_groups = data_from.node_groups
```

You can press <kbd>F3</kbd> in the Node Editor and search for the name of your node group and select it.

[image]

Comment: Yes but is there any way to do it without going through the blend file? So it's straight through the NodeTree file?

Comment: @ArsenHere i updated my answer. yes you can also do it via python and run the script to import all the node groups. then press `F3` in your node editor and search your custom node group :)